# Unhandled rejection TypeError: this.emitter.refreshFiles is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Im currently testing my angular app, it's using angular (1.5) + typescript(^1.8.0) + karma (^0.13.14);

I've got the following error when trying to run karma:

> "Unhandled rejection TypeError: this.emitter.refreshFiles is not a
>   function
>       at Plugin.notifyKarmaAboutChanges (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/karma-webpack-with-fast-source-maps/index.js:148:15)
>       at Plugin. (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/karma-webpack-with-fast-source-maps/index.js:104:9)
>       at Compiler.applyPlugins (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:25:14)
>       at Watching._done (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:93:17)
>       at Watching. (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:76:18)
>       at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:319:37)
>       at Watching. (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:59:19)
>       at /Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:312:11
>       at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:73:70)
>       at Compiler.afterEmit (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:309:8)
>       at Compiler. (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:14)
>       at /Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
>       at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
>       at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
>       at Compiler.emitFiles (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:272:20)
>       at MemoryFileSystem.(anonymous function) [as mkdirp] (/Users/roamer/Documents/work/project/asbhub/develop/asbhub-frontend/node_modules/karma-webpack-with-fast-source-maps/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:283:10)"

So I can only restart karma to run my test again instead of letting karma to auto refresh for me. Can't find similar issue on stackoverflow, so I post my issue here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try setting Karma v1.5.0. Cheers